# use of wow.min.js with jquery.fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, wow.js

I am using two famous plugins **wow.min.js** and **jquery.fullpage.js** but when I use both at same page one of them is not working, help me please. I am using these two scripts to call both of them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage'],
            sectionsColor: ['#97cbd6', '#40434b'],
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
            navigationTooltips: ['First page', 'Second page', 'Third and last page']
        });
    });
</script>




  <script>
        new WOW().init();
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Console error? Bad rendering? Not initializing?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to read the [fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions).

> Parallax, **as well as many other plugins which depends on the scrolling of the site**, listens the scrollTop property of javascript. fullPage.js doesn't actually scroll the site but it changes the top or translate3d property of the site. Only when using the fullPage.js option scrollBar:true or autoScrolling:false it will actually scroll the site in a way it is accessible for the scrollTop property.

So... just use `scrollBar:true`. 
Or use fullpage.js callbacks add or remove classes to create the animations, just as in the [Apple iPhone 5C demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/apple.html) available in the  examples folder of fullPage.js.